# Set sliders from a color

Tags: c#, wpf, argb

So I have some sliders that I use to set an "argb" color. After the window is closed the color is saved and all is good.

Is there anyway I can then set the sliders to be set to that color the next time I initiate the window without having to save each slider as a setting? Since the color is already being saved as a setting, can't I use "FromArgb" backwards somehow to find the a, r, g and b values?

Comment: I would use TwoWay data binding with a ValueConverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the whole argb value then you are looking for [`Color.ToArgb()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb(v=vs.110).aspx), which will get the 32-bit ARGB value of the `Color` structure.

Or as @Clemens correctly pointed out, you can just get each byte from [`A`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.a(v=vs.110).aspx), [`R`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.r(v=vs.110).aspx), [`G`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.g(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`B`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.b(v=vs.110).aspx) properties of the [`Color` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Color(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g. use `MyColor.A` to set the sliders value for A. use `Mycolor.B` to set the slider for B, etc.

Comment: The question is about WPF, so you would access the `A`, `R`, `G` and `B` properties of the WPF [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx) structure.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for the info, I have edited it into my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works exactly in terms of syntax, could you give me an example? Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: @Adkit, just use `Color.A`, `Color.B`... to set the value of your sliders. Updated.